# How to omit columns in react-virtualized MultiGrid?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

Using react-virtualized MultiGrid with AutoSizer, is there a way to omit a column from the data set dynamically?  I basically copied the example and setup the `_cellRenderer` to skip over a column on a condition, however it looks as if the column is still in the code:

```
_cellRenderer({columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style}) {
    let retVal = '';
     if(rowIndex === 1 && columnIndex === 5){
        retVal = null;
    } else {
        retVal = (<div className={styles.Cell} key={key} style={style}>
            {columnIndex}, {rowIndex}
        </div>)
    }

    return (retVal);
}
```

[image: Missing Column between 6:00 and 7:00 should collapse]

Comment: For removing a column, you should remove the item from the initial array.